# Transitioning from Google Maps SDK to Google Maps CocoaPod

Tags: xcode, swift, google-maps, cocoapods

I have been using the Google Maps iOS SDK in my app since the beginning. Today, I went to update the SDK only to find that Google only provides the SDK in CocoaPods now (new to me). I followed a tutorial to install CocoaPods and added the Google Maps reference in the Podfile. Now, when I go to build my project, I get errors related to the various linkers for the old SDK.

[image: Error Messages]

What must I do to safely complete the transition to the Google Maps CocoaPods SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out my problem. It turns out I just needed to delete the Google Maps Framework and add `$(inherited)` to my linkers. Everything is working with the new Google Maps SDK now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the workspace that cocopods created or the same xcode project file you had previously? With cocopods you need to open the workspace.